# embeddings $SU(2) \to SU(N)$ and representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

How can we prove that group immersions $SU(2) \to SU(N)$ (up to conjugacy) are in 1-1 correspondence with (non-trivial) $N$-dimensional representations of $SU(2)$ (up to equivalence)?

Feel free to slightly correct the above statement if necessary.

Cross-posted on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232431/embeddings-su2-to-sun-and-representations)

Comment: I don't have time to post a full answer, but, you should change "embeddings" to "immersions", and you should probably say something like "immersions up to conjugacy".  Likewise, you want $N$-dim reps of $SU(2)$ up to equivalence.  (Otherwise, there is a correspondence, but that's just because both have the cardinality of the real numbers.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito thanks, could you post a hint to answer?

Comment: I mispoke slightly above - you either need to take only non-trivial  representations, or allow any group homorphism $SU(2)\rightarrow SU(N)$.  Now, a hint:  given an immersion of $SU(2)$ into $SU(N)$, restrict the standard rep of $SU(N)$ on $\mathbb{C}^N$ to the image of $SU(2)$ to get a rep of $SU(2)$.  This process induces a bijection.

Comment: (This is a very poor hint - the only full proofs I know are non-trivial.  As another hint, the only proof I know uses results from Mal’cev, : On semisimple subgroups of Lie groups. Am. Math. Soc. Transl. 1, 172–273 (1950)

Comment: @JasonDeVito I see, thanks for the hint; feel free to add details should you have time later

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm actually feeling sick  In lieu of an anwswer, how bout some shameless self promotion?  In http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.05207 an undergrad and myself have to carry this out when $N = 4$.  (The actual paper is DeVito and DeYeso, III. Top. and Appl., Vol. 198 (2016), 86-100 )

Comment: The MathOF cross-post is here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/232431/ (and will perhaps be closed as the question belongs on here)